# Can I read data from Google Earth placemark data (.kmz) files?

Tags: google-earth

I recall that in a past version Google Earth stored placemark data in XML files with a .kml extension. For my current version (5.2.1.1547) however, I can't find such a file. And when I save a placemark to a file, GE creates a *binary* .kmz file.

Are the XML data files gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .KMZ file is a zipped archive to hold the .KML file and any associated images:

> KML files and their related images (if any) can be compressed using the ZIP format into KMZ archives.

[Source](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/)

So you should be able to open the file in something like WinZip or WinRar to extract the .KML file, edit it and then update it.